# How to loop over an array of objects and display it in UI using angular 8

Tags: angular8

I am trying to loop over an array of objects and display it in html using Angular 8.

My `app.component.ts` file is as shown below:

In the above code `uptimeDataSet` is the array of data that I need to loop over and display on another component.

My `app.component.html` file looks as shown below:

Finally, I am trying to loop over in my component to display the object in `uptime-chart-component.html` as below:

But I am not able to get the details in the UI. I am not able to find out where I am going wrong. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Please provide the app-uptime-chart .ts file

Comment: Have you used @Input in your child component to capture the value?

Comment: @pontusv the ts file doesn't have anythign related to the data. I am adding it below.

Comment: @Priyankarao I didn't get your question, sorry. Can you please elaborate

Comment: I have posted the answer . Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your uptime-chart.component.ts file-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uptime-chart',
  templateUrl: './uptime-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uptime-chart.component.css']
})
export class UptimeChartComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() chartData: any[];
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }

  
}
```

You need use @Input to capture the value in your child component. @Input decorator is used when you are passing data from parent to child. I suggest you take a look at this blog to understand- https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

And I believe, you can change your app.component.html without the *ngFor-

```
<app-user [chartData]="uptimeDataSet"></app-user>
```

if this is what you want your result to be